# Drupal 8 - custom Selection Handler for entity_autocomplete causes indefinite loading

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Due to some last minute changes in a project, I am trying to alter the results of an autocomplete field such as to remove certain nodes that have been tagged with a taxonomy term whose name is "Empty".

I have successfully created my own Selection Handler and it is being called on my custom form.

In my selection handler, I am making use of the `entityQueryAlter` method to add a condition to the query:

```
class MyCustomSelection extends NodeSelection {


  public function entityQueryAlter(SelectInterface $query) {

    parent::entityQueryAlter($query);


    //Get the tid for the term which was used to tag nodes which should be EXCLUDED from the results

    $emptyTid = array_values(\Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
      ->condition('name', 'Empty')
      ->execute())[0];

    if ($emptyTid != null && $emptyTid > -1) {

    //Get nids for nodes which were tagged with this term

      $excludeQuery = db_query('
        SELECT entity_id 
        FROM node__field_custom_tags 
        WHERE field_custom_tags_target_id = :tid', 

        array(
          ':tid' => $emptyTid
        )

      )->fetchAllKeyed(0, 0);

      //Reset array keys
      $result = array_values($excludeQuery);

      //Typecast all the values to int, just to be safe
      $typecastedResult = array();

      foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
        $typecastedResult[] = (int)$v;
      }

      //Add a condition to the query such as to exclude the nodes found above

      $query->condition('entity_id', $typecastedResult, 'NOT IN');

    }

    return $query;

  }
```

I understand that it is considered a best practice to use `db_select` over `db_query`, but the above method is returning the results I need and everything seems to be working as expected, except for the fact that my autocomplete field loads indefinitely ONLY if the `$query->condition` line is included:

```
$query->condition('entity_id', $typecastedResult, 'NOT IN');
```

The value in `$typecastedResult` is equivalent to the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 101
    etc...
)
```

Could someone please offer some insight as to why the autocomplete field would be loading indefinitely without results? Once again, it is the addition of the new condition which causes this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved this. For some reason I wasn't generating an error log. Having fixed that, the issue was simple => "entity_id" was erroneous since we're querying the node_field_data table. The correct field is node_field_data.nid. Most issues are due to simple errors :) .. how embarrassing